# Prove $|f^{(n)}(z_0)|\leq Mn!/R^n$, where $|f(z)| = M$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Given a circunference $\Gamma$ with radius $R$ and center $z_0$. Prove that if $f(z)$ is analytic in $\Gamma$ and their interior, then
\begin{equation*}
|f^{(n)}(z_0)|\leq \frac{Mn!}{R^n},
\end{equation*}
where $M$ is the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ in $\Gamma$.

Ok, here my attempt:

Since $f$ is analytic, then by Taylor theorem
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = \sum _{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_0)^n,
\end{equation*}
taking absolute value we obtain
\begin{equation*}
|f(z)| = \left|\sum _{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_0)^n\right| = \sum _{n = 0}^{\infty}|f^{(n)}(z_0)|\frac{|(z-z_0)^n|}{n!},
\end{equation*}
but, by definition, $M\geq |f(z)|$ and expanding the summation
\begin{equation*}
M\geq |f^0(z_0)|\frac{|z-z_0|^0}{0!}+|f^1(z_0)|\frac{|z-z_0|^1}{1!}+\cdots+|f^n(z_0)|\frac{|z-z_0|^n}{n!}+\cdots,
\end{equation*}
all terms in the summation are potisives, then if we take only the n-term we can assure that
\begin{equation*}
M\geq |f^{(n)}(z_0)|\frac{|z-z_0|^n}{n!}.
\end{equation*}

Ok here is my problem, if I say $|z-z_0|^n\geq R^n$, I'm finished, but $|z-z_0|\geq R$ is false. So, what did I do wrong?.

Comment: The expression $\left|\sum _{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_0)^n\right| = \sum _{n = 0}^{\infty}|f^{(n)}(z_0)|\frac{|(z-z_0)^n|}{n!}$ is not always true. This should not be an equality, but an inequality

Comment: Read 'Cauchy's estimates' in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @Denis28 Hahaha thanks, I forgot triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** By The Cauchy Integral Formula
$$\begin{equation*}
|f^{(n)}(z_0)|=  \left| \frac{n!}{2 \pi i}\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{|z-z_0|^{n+1}} dz \right| \leq  \frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_{\Gamma} \frac{\left|f(z)\right|}{|z-z_0|^{n+1}} dz 
\end{equation*}$$

Now use $|f(z)| \leq M$ on $\Gamma$. Also, on $\Gamma$ what is $|z-z_0|$?